# Having wp-admin on different domain

Tags: filters, wp-admin, domain

I had a wordpress wp-admin running on a different domain.

In other words `WP_SITEURL = 'https//admin.example.com'` and `WP_HOME = 'https://www.example.com'`

Recently I had the bad idea to updated wordpress to the latest version.

All seems work fine but after I realized that was impossibile add a new post or updated an existing one.

For example when I added a new post (/wp-admin/post-new.php) there were few fetch requests from admin to www:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=100&_locale=user
```

Both of them had the same error:

```
Access to fetch at
'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=100&_locale=user'
from origin 'https://admin.example.com' has been blocked by CORS
policy: Request header field x-wp-nonce is not allowed by
Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Looking around I found out that would be easy add a new CORS directive, so promptly added this:

```
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-WP-Nonce', false);
    return $value;
});
```

Ironically the result was even worst, now I have an infinite requests that fail with 403

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
...
```

Now I'm stuck trying to understand what's wrong, and if there is any way to solve this issue.

Any help to understand what's happening is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. The only difference is that the user is not allowed to access wp-admin directly through the domain application (security issues), only from one of the IP nodes from the cluster. So i'm facing a CORS problem because my IP_NODE is trying to access DOMAIN.com wp-json api. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: by the way. The 403 problem is because wp-nonce is a unique number used once for the transaction (like a cookie or something) and is pratically impossible to use it like a JWT behaviour or something (I the way that with jwt it is possible to inform that i'm a authenticated user and have permission to make this request)

Comment: Well after many many tries I gave up

Answer (score 0):

You could try to go through the SQL DB and find the references to admin.example and change them to example.com

Another way to do this is use a plugin like [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)